# Selenium webdriver Explicit conversion Exists

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

please can you give me an point whats wrong with:

```
public class WebDriverTest
{

    public void FacebookTest() 
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://facebook.com";


        IList<IWebElement> friends =  diver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='fsl fwb fcb']/a"));
        Console.WriteLine(friends.Count);
```

I am still getting

> Error code CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of web-elements you need `FindElements` (returns list) instead of `FindElement` (returns single element if exist). Try below:

```
IList<IWebElement> friends =  diver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='fsl fwb fcb']/a"));
```